# performance.now() timing erratic in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am using [performance.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29) to get a method start and end time. I have found the results in Firefox to be a fairly consistent 10-12 ms. In Chrome, the timings vary wildly from 30-70ms.

I am not concerned about the fact that Firefox runs faster (as browser JS implementations will vary) so much as the wide spread of results encountered in Chrome that makes getting an accurate result impossible. Comments in [this article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now) seem to imply that the Chrome implementation is only accurate to 1ms in any event - is this correct?

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what is going on, or how to produce more accurate and consistent performance evaluations?

Comment: Is it the execution time you're looking for then?

Comment: Yes it is the execution time I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of two problems. Either `performance.now()` is recording the wrong times (which seems unlikely), or Chrome is taking variable times to execute.

What you should do is test which one it is: use `Date.now()` instead of `performance` to find the execution time: if it stabilises, the problem is in `performance.now()`, otherwise it's Chrome.

The main advantage of `performance` is documented as being that it can record up to 1 microsecond's accuracy. However, this is unlikely to be required for the vast majority of problems, so using `Date` instead may well sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is late, but performance.now is accurate, however chrome's v8 engine does crazy optimization on the code, and thats were the inconsistencies come from. the variation in time is case specific, since v8 does optimizations, and if you force it to de-optimize (ex. changing variable type from string to number) it will cost a lot performance wise.
additionally calling the same pure function multiple times will make v8 engine optimize it, hence it will become almost instantaneous over several repetitions.

if you share the code with me i can help you out with your specific case.

Comment: In my specific case I've changed jobs several times since I posted this in 2014 :)